# What to include in Software design specification(SDS) document

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, documentation, specifications, software-design

I am a ruby on rails developer. For my project i m writing an API calls.  Angularjs will consume this API to show data on webpage.

I am good in coding but this is for the first time i will be creating  SDS document.. I dont know what to lnclude in my SDS document...

I have searches on the internet about sds and found lotnof articles on it but many of them were very high level difficult to understand document .

what i should write in my SDS document  As my rails code is all about API call...??  Plase share the sample document if possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should at least include some basic explanations in your SDS, even if the code is simple as you say.

Purpose, scope, used patterns(if any), database specifics, are basic sections this document should have. Sequence diagrams won't hurt too, they are great for explaining actual processes and flow

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.